# Arduino + LS7407N to shift logic levels in serial communication

Tags: arduino, serial, buffer, open-collector

I'm trying to drive a device that uses 12-0V levels for serial communication. I decided to use LS7407N, a buffer with open-collector, so that I can use Arduino's TTL levels to send commands to the device. The problem is that the device doesn't seem to get any messages. I am almost certain that the circuit is connected properly. As for the software, I'm only using Tx line to transfer the command and print out the result from the device. I do not have an oscilloscope, so I can't really see how the LS7407 chip works, but I tried several I bought yesterday and still get nothing.

Here is the circuit:
[image]

Maybe there's something wrong with the design? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where's the 0V end of the 12 v supply connected?

Comment: One little tip, if you don't have a scope the Arduino / AVR will support a really low baud rate like say 75 BPS that you'd be able to see toggling with a LED to make sure the signal is at least generally getting through.

Comment: 12V comes from an adapter (230V-12V), which can source up to 5A. Both adapter's and Arduino's GND are connected. 

I will try to use the low baud rate, but I'm pretty sure nothing is being transfered to the device because I would at least get an error response. The devices Tx line is properly connected to the Arduino and getting feedback works, it has been tested using a different external device to send the commands.

Comment: You show a block pinned out 16,15 with 16 labeled "+12V" and 15 labeled "RXD1".  What is that?

Comment: That is the device's connector. This is the part regarding the serial communication. There are also Tx and Res signals, which work and are not directly related to Rx, the rest of the pins are labeled N/C

Comment: @Bart: If the device works with an external signal source which replaces the Arduino, then the fault lies either in the Arduino or in the connections to the '07.  If it works with the external signal source connected to the device's RX input, then the fault could lie in either the Arduino, the '07, or the connections between them.  BTW, are you sure the 5V from the Arduino is hot and getting to the '07?

Comment: I've added LEDs so that I could see if the data is transferred/received on every Tx/Rx line. I checked the Vcc on the LS chip and it was 3.7 (but the diodes indicated that still the data is somehow being transferred). I made a simple voltage divider and connected the LS through the adapter, so now I have steady 5.05V on LS's Vcc with 55mA (which is a little high I think). Previously I was using 5V from Arduino for the LED's and in hindsight it wasn't really a good idea. Now the 5V rail comes from the adapter. I'm running out of ideas on how to test it without the oscilloscope...

Comment: @EMFields: One more clue I got is when the Arduino acts as a proxy, getting commands from external device, and then sending it through Tx to the LS and then to the device, nothing happens. But when I connect the test device's Tx line not to Arduino, but to the LS's input - the device starts to send feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't a design flaw.

tl;dr: **Devices parity was set to EVEN**.

Because of that, the messages from Arduino (with parity set to NONE) were coming in distorted. In case of loss of data the device simply doesn't provide any feedback.

My biggest mistake was assuming that the device parity was set to NONE. This conclusion came to me when I was receiving test device's messages with Arduino, and then simply displaying them. I'm not sure why, but they have appeared correctly using NONE. And also using EVEN. Yet the device doesn't work when Arduino is trying to send something using NONE. I changed it to EVEN and the communication works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I noticed there's no connection between the collector and the cap. Don't know what I was thinking so disregard my answer.

[A 100nF capacitor on the secondary side of the optocoupler gives a time constant of t = R*C = 4,7k * 100n = 0,47ms. Is this an OK rise time for the baud rate you are using?]

//Hank

Comment: According to the datasheet and lack of a shown junction dot it's just decoupling for the regulator and not connected to the output.

Comment: With Arduino I'm using the same baud rate (9600) as is used by the external device used for testing. The external test device (of which circuitry I have no idea) sends commands to my device, and I am able to read both, the commands and the devices feedback with my Arduino. The only problem is sending test commands from Arduino to the connected device, which are exactly the same as used by the testing device.

Comment: Is there a datasheet for the LS7407? I can't seem to locate one...

Comment: @HenrikSöderholtz: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls07.pdf